# Troubleshooting: iMac SSD appears then disappears

Tags: imac, startup, ssd, error, fusion-drive

I have a 27" iMac (18,3) that originally came with a 2TB Fusion drive. Last week, the iMac started showing signs of HDD failure so I swapped out the main drive with an SSD from OWC.

After installing the SSD, I installed macOS Sierra then upgraded to Monterey. I did not reset the Fusion drive and left the internal PCIe unformatted. After installing Monterey, I turned on FileVault. After using the iMac for a while, I returned and the iMac did not wake from sleep. I rebooted, entered my credentials, and the progress bar advanced about 1/3rd of the way before the screen went black displaying a circle with a line through it.

I rebooted into macOS Recovery, opened Disk Utility, and the OWC SSD was not in the list of devices. The only device showing was the PCIe drive. I unplugged the iMac for a few minutes, then rebooted and the drive was there. After a short while, the machine stopped responding, I rebooted and the SSD was gone.

Back in macOS Recovery, I installed Sierra then Monterey to the PCIe drive. A few reboots later, the OWC SSD decides to show up again. I've now got two drives on my desktop, each with macOS Monterey. I can switch startup disks and boot into either one. Sooner or later, I'm sure the SSD will probably disappear again.

I ran Apple Diagnostics (aka Apple Hardware Test) and it did not detect any issues. Both drives report S.M.A.R.T. status of "Verified". There are no issues reported by Disk Utility's First Aid.

I'm going to reopen the iMac and make sure all the connections inside are secure, though I don't think that's the problem. Otherwise, what could be the issue?

Is there any software-based diagnostics tool that can give me more information about what might be happening? Perhaps there's a controller or logic board malfunction, but I haven't been able to locate anything in the logs that might be related.

A troubleshooting plan would be appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I pulled the OWC SSD out of the iMac and connected it to my MacBook Pro via an external cable. I ran `diskutil eraseDisk`, formatted it to HFS+, then reinstalled it back into the iMac. Once in the iMac, I booted into macOS Recovery and installed Monterey to the SSD.

No problems during the installation (Monterey updated the format to APFS). It took about 35-40 minutes. Once I was able to log in to the OS, I started setting things up in System Preferences. After about 5 minutes of making changes, I clicked the "Users & Groups" preference pane. The beachball appeared and continued for about 10 minutes before I did a hard reset of the Mac via the power button.

Rebooted into macOS Recovery and the OWC SSD was not there.

AHT is still not reporting any issues.

**UPDATE #2**

I installed an older SSD in the iMac and about halfway through Monterey GUI installer, I got a "download error". I quit out of the installer, opened Terminal, and the drive is not listed in `diskutil list`.

AHT is *still* not reporting any issues.

Comment: I mean, it's pretty clear that software isn't causing this. You're almost definitely looking at a marginal hardware issue. I would start with OWC tech support, which will probably recommend that you exchange the SSD.

Comment: I'm positive it's not software, but none of the hardware is reporting an error, which I would've expected. Original HDD fails, newly purchased SSD is failing...I've got some older SSDs from previous laptops in the garage that I'll look for and install. At the moment, the connection to the iMac is the constant. I've reached out to OWC and am awaiting a reply. Thanks for the comment!